# Destroying a vector of ALLEGRO_BITMAP*

Tags: c++, vector, memory-leaks, allegro, allegro5

I use library Allegro5.
In my class named Animation I have `vector<ALLEGRO_BITMAP*> sprites`.
In constructor, I populate it with some bitmaps and in destructor I would like to delete it properly. However, my solutions still lead to memory leaking:

```
for each (ALLEGRO_BITMAP* it in sprites)
{
    al_destroy_bitmap(it);
}

for (auto it : sprites)
    delete it;

sprites.~vector();
```

or any other combination of those.

I really can't find out why it isn't deleting properly.

EDIT:

Now I have this and there is still a small memory leak, but in the size less then 1 MB

```
class Deleter
{
public:
void operator()(ALLEGRO_BITMAP* ptrToBitmap)
    {
        cout << "deleted"<<'\n';
        al_destroy_bitmap(ptrToBitmap);
    }
};
```

and

```
vector<unique_ptr<ALLEGRO_BITMAP, Deleter>> sprites;

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP* temp = al_load_bitmap("Fireball1.png");
    unique_ptr<ALLEGRO_BITMAP, Deleter> uptr;
    uptr = unique_ptr<ALLEGRO_BITMAP, Deleter>(temp);

    sprites.push_back(move(uptr));
}

sprites.~vector();
```

Comment: What is that for each? Why dont you call al_destroy_bitmap(*it) in the range based for before deleting *it.

Comment: It was just for testing, works the same, but you are right I should rather posted it this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make `sprites` a `std::vector<ALLEGRO_BITMAP*>`, make it a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ALLEGRO_BITMAP*,al_destroy_bitmap>>`.  That way, when the destructor of `sprites` is called (or when you resize it to zero), the unique_ptr destructor will free the bitmap.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. I don't know anything about unique_ptr so far, so please wait for my acceptance of the answer until I learn enought about it and then test it. (tomorrow)

Comment: I tried but I can't figure out how to make al_destroy_bitmap as deleter...

Comment: You may need to create a class which has an `operator()` and call `al_destroy_bitmap` from that.

Comment: I made it as you told but it doesn't call this function in destruction of the vector. My code is written as EDIT in my question above.

Comment: I figured out why and now it calls deleters. However, it still leaves occupied the size of pointers themselves.